# Rename files using batch file script

Tags: file, batch-file, rename

I want to rename the all `PDF` files in folder using batch script. for example i have 3 files in folder:-

```
anyfile.pdf
otherfile.pdf,
another.pdf
```

Now i want to rename file as bellow:-

```
PDF0.pdf
PDF1.pdf,
PDF2.pdf
```

i have fetch the files using this script:-

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
SET "r=%__CD__%"
FOR /R . %%F IN (*.pdf) DO (
 SET "p=%%F"
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  ECHO(!p:%r%=!
ENDLOCAL
  ) 
pause
```

now i can rename please help me.

Thanks

Comment: what is the criteria for naming? How they should be sorted - alphabetically , from date of creation/modification/.. , size , something else?

Comment: @npocmaka file name should be prefix with `PDF` and plus for loop index like `0` or `1` so on..

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for the command to rename files? Its `ren`. Look at http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html for more info.

Answer (score 0):

`FOR /R` and the string replacement to get rid of the path seem unnecessary here, since you stay within one directory.
(generally, if you want to get of the path, just say `%%~nxF`which returns the Name and eXtension of %%F.)

you can perform arithmetics, ie. count a number up, with `SET /A`, so you could do simply

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set i=0
FOR %%F IN (*.pdf) DO (
  set /a i=i+1
  ren %%F PDF!i!.pdf
) 
pause
```